# Wildcard SyntaxError in Snakemake with no obvious cause

Tags: snakemake

I keep getting an error about a rule not having the same wildcards in its output rules and I can't figure out what the source of the error might be:

```
SyntaxError:
Not all output, log and benchmark files of rule bcftools_filter contain the same wildcards. This is crucial though, in order to avoid that two or more jobs write to the same file.

...

rule merge_YRI_GTEx:
    input:
        kg=expand("kg_vcf/1kg_yri_chr{q}.vcf.gz", q=range(1,23)),
        gtex=expand("gtex_vcf/gtex_chr{v}.snps.recode.vcf.gz", v=range(1, 23))
    output:
        "merged/merged_chr{i}.vcf.gz"
    shell:
        "bcftools merge \
            -0 \
            -O z \
            -o {output} \
            {input.kg} \
            {input.gtex}"


rule bcftools_filter:
    input:
        expand("merged/merged_chr{i}.vcf.gz", i=range(1,23))
    output:
        filt="filtered_vcf/merged_filtered_chr{i}.vcf.gz",
        chk=touch(".bcftools_filter.chkpnt")
    threads:
        4
    shell:
        "bcftools filter \
            --include 'AN=1890 && AC > 0' \
            --threads {threads} \
            -O z \
            -o {output.filt} \
            {input}"
...
rule list_merged_filtered_vcfs:
    input:
        ".bcftools_filter.chkpnt"
    output:
        "processed_vcf_list.txt"
    shell:
        "for i in {{1..22}}; do \ "
        "echo \"{config[sprime_dir]}/filtered_vcf/merged_filtered_chr${{i}}.vcf.gz\" >> \
        {output}; done"
```

The specific line it's complaining about is the one that's just `"bcftools filter \` which is even more dumbfounding to me. I've tried giving names to the input wildcard and even scrutinizing the rule which calls `bcftools_filter`'s `output` as well as the rule which produces `bcftools_filter`'s `input` to no avail. Not sure what is giving me this error.

Comment: I don't see any issues in this code. Anyway, it is quite suspicious that you are using the same name `{i}` for both wildcard and the parameter in `expand`. Did you try to rename the wildcard to something more meaningful than just a single letter? Could you please provide the minimal code that shows the issue (I expect that you have side effects from something like wildcard constraints)?

Comment: I've tried using different names for the output wildcard to no avail. I am not using wildcard constraints. I'll update the post with more context (i.e. the rule that feeds into it and the rule which takes its output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error comes from `chk=touch(".bcftools_filter.chkpnt")` not containing the wildcard `{i}`.

Apart from that, I'm not sure you rule is very sensible. You are passing to `bcftools filter` a list of input files (from `expand(...)`) but I don't think bcftools filter accept more than one input file. Also, your rule will create output files `filtered_vcf/merged_filtered_chr{i}.vcf.gz` (one for each value of i) using the same list of input files. Are you sure you want `expand("merged/merged_chr{i}.vcf.gz", i=range(1,23))` instead of just `"merged/merged_chr{i}.vcf.gz"`, with values for i given somewhere upstream?

Comment: I'm trying to create a set of 22 parallel jobs all using `bcftools filter`, so each job is running `bcftools filter` with just one input.

I'm not sure how to do what you are recommending to me re: giving values upstream for the input files I am using in this rule. I've done the same thing elsewhere in my code with no problem. [Here's](https://github.com/aseyedia/neand_sQTL) the link to my project, the rule in this post is in `sprime_prep_Snakefile` and the error is giving `line 97`. The output from that rule is used in `sprime_combine_Snakefile` on `line 48`.